# Pyeda: infix form of boolean expression

Tags: python, pyeda

[Pyeda](http://pyeda.readthedocs.io/en/latest) permits to write boolean expression in prefix form and in infix form:

```
p = Or(And("A","B"), And("C","D")) # prefix
i = expr("A & B | C & D") # infix
```

Although it's possible to retrieve automatically from `i` the relative prefix form, I don't know (no findings in docs) if it's possible to retrieve the string **infix** representation of `p` .

Some helps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PyEDA author here.

The latest release doesn't have this feature. If you go back to version 0.26.0, you can try the `to_latex` and `to_unicode` methods.

For example:

```
>>> p = Or(And("A","B"), And("C","D"))
>>> p.to_unicode()
'A · B + C · D'
```

IIRC, the reason for this omission was the switch from Python to C for the boolean expression engine. A couple undocumented features just got left out b/c it was either difficult, or broken.

PRs welcome, of course :)

Comment: this is a pity. anyway chris, another question. there is a way to neutralize a formula? eg. from And(Or(a,b), And(None,c)) to And(Or(a,b))

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "neutralize" here. Maybe something like a tree manipulation where you delete nodes directly? No, I don't think I have implemented that kind of transform. Your example will return a Zero object, b/c the None will be interpreted as "Falsey" and force the inner and outer And to zero. You can try using identities to eliminate nodes differently than dominators.

Comment: Hi @Christ Drake how can i install the 0.26.0 version?